# Finding conjugate of a complex number using some algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

it is given that z is a complex number satisfying

> $z^3-iz+1=0$

I'm supposed to find argument of  $ z+z \bar z + \bar z$

The only thing I could do was

$(z+1)(z^2+1-z)=iz$

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Find the number or its argument ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust argument

Comment: Isn't $ z+z\bar z+ \bar z$ always real?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, so the argument is either $0$ or $\pi$.  But [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2Re%28z%29%2B%7Cz%7C%5E2%2C+where+z%5E3-iz%2B1%3D0) says both cases occur

Comment: @saulspatz : Ah!  :-(

Comment: @ancientmathematician    So can I say there are two answers possible since it was a subjective question

Comment: No you need to check whether some roots give  $0$ and some give $\pi$ as @saulspatz points out. I can't see easily why both occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$z+z\bar z+\bar z=2\Re(z)+|z|^2.$$

You still have to find out the sign.